# Drawing on top of an image to create an animation

Tags: android

I'm new on Android, and I am having trouble with the following:

I have an image of an empty test-tube (png or bmp).
And I need to draw lines on top of it to make the illusion that its being filled in with liquid.

I really don't know how to proceed. I have read google's documentation about animations, but that didn't help much.
I'd appreciate if you guys could give me some suggestions of how it can be done, and point to some tutorials/documentation that can help me.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
The tube is not retangular, the bottom is oval.
I think I need to make the liquid fall into the test tube, then paint line by line, starting from the bottom. And I have to check for the borders of the tube (right and lef black pixels).
Any ideas of how this can be done?

UPDATE 2:
Here is the tube image: http://i61.tinypic.com/2nw0eb9.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SurfaceView to draw what ever you want:

Basicly, you lock the surface's canvas by 
`Canvas canvas = mSurfaceView.getHolder().lockCanvas();`
Then, use the canvas's methods to draw on it. `canvas.drawBitmap`, `canvas.drawLine` etc..
When you're finished lock the canvas with `mSurfaceView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);` and you're done.

here's an example from a quick google search:
http://android-coding.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/drawing-on-surfaceview.html

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this would be with a custom View. Make a new class, that extends View, then in its onDraw method first draw the picture, then draw your animations. If you want to do it by hand, you can do something like this:

```
private class TestTubeView extends View {

    private int top = 0;

    private Paint myPaint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //First draw your bitmap
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_testtube), 0, 0, myPaint); //might need to use a different paint

        //Then your "animation" as a static image, that has its position set from a variable, in this case "y" and "x"
        canvas.drawRect(0, top, getWidth(), getHeight(), myPaint);
    }

    //In this method update your variables, that define the positions of your animated lines / bubbles
    public boolean updateAnimation() {
        top++;
        invalidate();

        //So it stops animationg
        return top > getHeight();
    }
}
```

Then in your layout you put it in like a normal view:

```
<com.example.TestTubeView
    android:id="@+id/my_testtube"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

And then you animate it with a self-repeating Runnable:

```
    final MyView testTube = findViewById(R.id.my_testtube);
    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(testTube.updateAnimation()){
                myHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
            }
        }
    });
```

You'll have to play around with sizes / heights and things like that though. Another way of doing this is with an  `ObjectAnimatior`

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and couldn't figure it out what to do with the last piece of code.. The way I did I keep getting null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Why don't you share the tube image with us?

Comment: The image is available now :)

Answer (score 0):

Tube Drawable: (this is for test purposes. you will use your tube image)
**tube.xml** (drawable folder)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#ffccffff" />
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

**tube_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/orangeJuiceLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#fff58225">

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tubeImageView"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/tube"
            android:onClick="fillJuice"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**TubeAcivity.java**

```
public class TubeActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout orangeLL;
    ImageView tubeIV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tube_activity);

        orangeLL = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.orangeJuiceLinearLayout);
        tubeIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tubeImageView);

    }

    public void fillJuice(View view) {

        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, tubeIV.getMeasuredHeight());
        va.setDuration(1500);
        va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                orangeLL.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                orangeLL.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        va.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think that's gonna work for me... The tube is not retangular.. and I need the liquid to fill in the test tube little by little. I guess I will need to check for the black borders of the image...So I would stop painting a line when I reach a black pixel (left or right border), then I paint the next line, and so on